# C++ not calling derived class function when passing by const reference

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

The following is an abstract of my code:

**Base class:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
    Base() { cout << "Base constructor" << endl; }
    ~Base() { cout << "Base destructor" << endl; }
    virtual void func(void) const { cout << "base" << endl; }
};
```

**Derived class:**

```
#include "Base.h"
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() { cout << "Derived constructor" << endl; }
    ~Derived() { cout << "Derived destructor" << endl; }
    void func(void) const { cout << "derived" << endl; }
};
```

**Test class:**

```
#include "Derived.h"

class Test {
public:
    const Base& base;
    Test(const Base& _base) : base(_base) { cout << "Test constructor" << endl; }
    void test() { base->func(); }
    ~Test() { cout << "Test destructor" << endl; }
};
```

**main function for testing:**

```
#include "Test.h"
int main(void) {
    Test* t = new Test(Derived());
    t->test();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the main function, the **Base** version of **func** is being called.

However, if I change the main function to the following:

```
#include "Test.h"
int main(void) {
    Derived d;
    Test* t = new Test(d);
    t->test();
    return 0;
}
```

The **Derived** version of **func** is correctly called.
I also tried to change **const Base& base** in **Test** to **Base* base**. And then construct **Test** using

```
Test* t = new Test(new Derivec())
```

It turns out that the **Derived** version of **func** is also correctly being called.

I was thinking that if I use either reference or pointer, the polymorphism is going to work.

Can anyone explain to me why the first version does not call the derived class method correctly?

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: First of all, this code has undefined behavior. Second of all, this code should not compile. Third of all, this code has non-virtual destructor in polymorphic class.

Comment: @SergeyA: Don't worry about virtual destructor, there are no `delete` :-/

Comment: Sorry! The non-virtual destructor is a typo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a dangling reference problem.

```
Test* t = new Test(Derived());
```

You are using a temporary object of type `Derived` to construct `t`. The temporary object gets deleted after the constructor of `Test` returns.

Hence, your program has undefined behavior.

If you use

```
Derived d;
Test* t = new Test(d);
```

you get the expected behavior because `t` does not have a dangling reference.

---

Also note that

```
void test() { base->func(); }
```

should not compile since `base` is a reference. That lines needs to be:

```
void test() { base.func(); }
```

Comment: That code can't be compiled. Low quality questions do not deserve the answer!

Comment: But is this essentially the same as passing an r-value as a reference to const?

Comment: @Guignol, the reference is valid as long as you are inside the function call, in this case the constructor. The reference is not valid after the function returns.

Comment: I understand it now! Thank you so much for helping!